# ScaleTransition from a Card to Full Screen Widget

Tags: flutter

I have a grid of cards that on onTap, I would like it to Expand to fill the screen. Just like on iOS when we click on a app launcher icon.

I manage to get it to expand, but it is always from the middle of the screen, with this:

```
 onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(new PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder:
            (BuildContext context, Animation animation,
                Animation secondaryAnimation) {
          return MyWidget();
        }, transitionsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
            Widget child) {
          return Align(
            child: ScaleTransition(
              child: child,
              scale: animation,
            ),
          );
        }));
      }
```

I saw that ScaleTransition have a alignment, but I couldn't figure out how to use that to set it to the point in the middle of my Card.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the alignment based on the context of your page and context of your widget, here is a complete example with a route:

```
class ParentChildContainerTransformRoute<T> extends MaterialPageRoute<T> {
  ParentChildContainerTransformRoute({
    required WidgetBuilder builder,
    required GlobalKey animateFromWidgetKey,
    required this.context,
    RouteSettings? settings,
  }) : super(builder: builder, settings: settings) {
    var renderbox = animateFromWidgetKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    var position = renderbox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    var pagesize = context.size;
    var ax = position.dx / pagesize!.width;
    var ay = position.dy / pagesize!.height;
    debugPrint('alignment calculated: $ax, $ay');
    transitionFromAlignment = Alignment(ax, ay);
  }

  late Alignment transitionFromAlignment;
  final BuildContext context;

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
    var anim = CurvedAnimation(curve: Curves.easeInOutCubicEmphasized, parent: animation);
    return ScaleTransition(scale: anim, alignment: transitionFromAlignment, child: child);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
   Map? pageArguments = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      ParentChildContainerTransformRoute(
        builder: (context) => SummaryDetailsPage(comment: widget.template.details),
        animateFromWidgetKey: editDetailsButtonKey,
        context: context,
      ),
    );
```